# How does pandas handle duplicate index?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two `pandas.Series` with duplicate indexes, something like this:

```
>> x = pandas.Series(range(5,10), index = ['a' for _ in xrange(5)])
>> y = pandas.Series(range(-5,-10, -1), index = ['a' for _ in xrange(5)])
```

which look like this

```
      x  y
   a  5 -5
   a  6 -6
   a  7 -7
   a  8 -8
   a  9 -9
```

Then when executing `x+y`, I get a `pandas.Series` of 0's. It seems as if it follows the order instead of the index which may or may not be the intended behavior.

Any idea on how is this handled in `pandas` and if this is indeed the intended behavior (i.e. I should always expect the same behavior) ?

EDIT:
Note that pandas do element-wise sum according to index, i.e.:

```
>> pd.Series([1,2], index=['a', 'b']) + pd.Series([-1,-2], index=['b', 'a'])
a   -1
b    1
```

Comment: What is your intended/expected output?

Comment: My expectation would be that it should raise an Exception... It could hide nasty bugs, at least it did for my case.

Comment: What bug? When you do `x+y`, it performs element-wise sum, which is the expected behavior.

Comment: element-wise sum according to index! Let say I had pd.Series([1,2], index=['a', 'b']) and pd.Series([-1,-2], index=['b', 'a']) I won't get [0,0] but [-1,1]

Comment: Can you edit your question according to your last comment?

Comment: Another good example to add, do `y.index = ['a','a','a','b','a']` and then `x + y`.

Comment: How about using `pd.Series(x.values + y.values)`?

Comment: Thanks, I edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think pandas ignores the index when all the values are the same. If you add another value you get a different result:

```
x = pd.Series(range(5,10), index = ['a' for _ in range(4)]+['b'])
y = pd.Series(range(-5,-10, -1), index = ['b']+['a' for _ in range(4)])
```

with

```
x

a    5
a    6
a    7
a    8
b    9
```

and

```
y

b   -5
a   -6
a   -7
a   -8
a   -9
```

Now, you get the following result:

```
x+y

a   -1
a   -2
a   -3
a   -4
a    0
a   -1
a   -2
a   -3
a    1
a    0
a   -1
a   -2
a    2
a    1
a    0
a   -1
b    4
```

The duplicated indices result in additional rows for all possible matches on `'a'` in `x` and `y`.

Comment: Thank you and nice catch! This does not make any sense for me tbh.

Answer (score 0):

**Based on @othman-nejjar's comment**

You can use:

```
pd.Series([1,2], index=['a', 'b']).add(pd.Series([-1,-2], index=['b', 'a']))
```

Output:

```
a   -1
b    1
dtype: int64
```